# Failed to lookup javax.naming.NamingException java.lang.InstantiationError

Tags: websocket, ejb, ejb-3.0, wildfly

When I saw the wildfly server logs, Lookups were properly added.

What could be the reason for instantiation error ? Kindly help me on this.

Ear -- (War + jar) : "War" is getting accesed from the "jar"

To make that connection possible, I exposed the WebsocketSessionHandlerLogic as Local interface

WebsocketSessionHandler is inside "XXXXX.war"  are as follows:

```
java:global/governor.beans/XXXXXX/WebsocketSessionHandler!XXXXXX.WebsocketSessionHandler
java:app/XXXXXX/WebsocketSessionHandler!XXXXXX.WebsocketSessionHandler
java:module/WebsocketSessionHandler!XXXXXX.WebsocketSessionHandler
java:global/governor.beans/XXXXXX/WebsocketSessionHandler
java:app/XXXXXX/WebsocketSessionHandler
java:module/WebsocketSessionHandler


 try {
                sessionHandler = (WebsocketSessionHandlerLogic) new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/governor.beans/XXXX/WebsocketSessionHandler!XXXXX.WebsocketSessionHandler");
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                throw new EJBException(e);
            }
            session =  sessionHandler.getSession(device);
```

Following are the logs when the above Snippets are executed

2015-03-23 18:54:47,573 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (EJB default - 2) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: JBAS011878: Failed to lookup governor.beans/XXXX-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/WebsocketSessionHandler!XXXXX.WebsocketSessionHandler [Root exception is java.lang.InstantiationError: XXXXXX.WebsocketSessionHandler$$$view13]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exposed the WebsocketSessionHandlerLogic as @Remote interface, and it was working fine for me